# Computing a complicated integral $ \int_0^r \frac{x}{(1+x)^2 [1+(Qx)^\delta]} \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to compute the integral:
$$ \int_0^r \frac{x}{(1+x)^2 [1+(Qx)^\delta]} \mathrm{d}x $$

The assumptions here are that $Q>0$, $r>0$, and $\delta > 0$, all real. I'm having trouble getting Mathematica to evaluate the integral, and I'm hoping for a reasonably simple analytical expression but don't know how to attempt to evaluate the integral. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would be surprised if that had _any_ kind of analytical solution, never mind a reasonably simple one.

Comment: @TonyK Even for rational values of $\delta$?

Comment: Need $\delta$ to be real but not rational. It's okay if there is no analytical solution, just would like to know for sure. I'm trying to speed up a computation that will evaluate this integral many times for different values of Q, r, and delta.

Comment: @Allawonder: indeed, if $\delta$ is rational, [this nifty tool](https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/calculus/integral-calculator.php) often gives an explicit form for the (indefinite) integral. But putting $\delta=e$, say, results in "integral could not be found".

Comment: @SheridanBeckwithGreen If $\delta$ is rational, then you can rationalize the integrand with $x=t^{n}$ where $n$ is the denominator of $\delta$, and in theory, a closed form exists (but probably hard to find). If it's irrational, a closed-form looks very unlikely.